# regex lookbehind ignore quotes

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I have the below string in my file and I want to extract the word after `-s`,  i.e `yesterday` without quotes  :

```
-t -w -g london -s 'yesterday' -e 'yesterday' -f 100000"
```

**Required output**

```
yesterday
```

**What I have tried**

- First attempt:

  ```
  grep -oP '(?<=\-s )\w*.*'
  ```

  This resulted in

  ```
  'yesterday' -e 'yesterday' -f 100000
  ```

  But sometimes I may get the content like below also, i.e without any quotes or with double quotes also

  ```
  -t -w -g london -s "yesterday" -e 'yesterday' -f 100000"
  -t -w -g london -s yesterday -e yesterday -f 100000"
  ```
- Second attempt:

  ```
  grep -oP '(?<=\-s )\w*'
  ```

  Here I got only single quotes in output.

Unsure how to proceed on the above situation.

Comment: Is there really a trailing, unpaired double quote on the line?

Comment: @glennjackman -yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative (GNU) `grep`, given the sample input:

```
-t -w -g london -s 'yesterday' -e 'yesterday' -f 100000"
-t -w -g london -s "yesterday" -e 'yesterday' -f 100000"
-t -w -g london -s yesterday -e yesterday -f 100000"
```

```bsh
$ grep -oP "(?<=-s \"|-s '|-s )[^'\" ]*" file
yesterday
yesterday
yesterday
```

Answer (score 2):

A relatively simpler approach, over the lookbehind regex is to extract the string with the quotes (single or double) and trim it out later (GNU grep)

```bsh
grep -oP -- '-s\s*\K([^ ]+)' file | tr -d \'\"
```

Comment: Can you help me understand the above expression. bit curious why s* is part of the expression. and what is the use of --

Comment: Regex 101 is a good place to dissect the regexes - https://regex101.com/r/jQuhoA/1 . `\s*` matches any whitespace character zero to unlimited times. `--` is a shell construct to signal end of command line options

Comment: Thanks for the info